# How separate variables in Pandas based on space and comma

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I need to remove a word after a separation after each comma. For example, if the first index in a column is

```
'stack overflow, ask question , keep remove'
```

(note that they are all in one sting)

I need the output to be,

```
'stack, ask, keep'
```

(this is in one string)

so the first word is kept and the rest of words removed after each comma.
I used .split but I did not get the result.
Here is my approach,

```
 final_re= [mydf.mycolumn.str.split(' ')[index][0] for index in range(0, len(mydf))]
```

In this case, it keeps the first word that means if the input is

```
'stack overflow, ask question , keep remove'
```

my output would be just

```
'stack'
```

however, I need the out put to be

```
'stack, ask, keep'
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You have to try first and ask issues in your try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import pandas as pd

row = [['stack overflow', 'ask question', 'keep remove'],
       ['stack overflow', 'ask question', 'keep remove']]
df = pd.DataFrame(row)
func = lambda x: re.findall('(\w+) \w+', x)[0] if re.findall('(\w+) \w+', str(x)) else x
df = df.applymap(func)
print(df.head())
```

You can use a regex to capture the first word indicated by (\w+) and ignoring words after the space, indicated by a space and \w+. If it finds a string such as this, meaning a word just before a space, it will replace the original string with this word. If it doesn't find it, it will leave it as it is.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.